# .ajax call not getting to my controller... Not sure why

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to get an Ajax call to my controller and pass back a string... for some reason, I am unable to get down into my controller...
Not sure what I am missing...

```
$.ajax({
                url: dummyURL,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#resultDiv').append('<b>' + result + '</b>');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location = RedirectUrl;
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
```

This is how I set up my url string:

```
var dummyURL = '@Url.Action("AddPatient", "AddFoundPatient", new { FirstName = "-1", LastName = "-2", DOB = "-3", MRN = "-4", EMPIID = "-5", popID = (int)TempData["POPULATIONID"] })';

var FName = rowData['First_Name'];
            var LName = rowData['Last_Name'];
            var DOB = rowData['DOB'];
            var MRN = rowData['medipacId'];
            var EMPIID = rowData['EMPIID'];
            //Add Patient call
            var path = dummyURL.replace("-1", FName);
            path = path.replace("-2", LName);
            path = path.replace("-3", DOB);
            path = path.replace("-4", MRN);
            path = path.replace("-5", EMPIID);
```

This is the Action method that I am attempting to call...

```
public string AddFoundPatient(string FirstName, string LastName, string DOB, string MRN, string EMPIID, int popID)
```

This is the query string that I generate...

```
/AddFoundPatient/AddPatient?FirstName=BETTY &amp;LastName=WHITE &amp;DOB=1925-10-25 &amp;MRN=840108105 &amp;EMPIID=11011833 &amp;popID=2
```

I never hit the debbugging statements inside my action... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's something about the way ASP.NET syntax and JavaScript syntax overlap that makes me feel like I'm reading a foreign language. Or maybe advanced calculus.

Comment: Did you run Firebug or the Chrome/IE developer tools? Is the request even being made? To what URL?

Comment: Does the ajax call give an error? You can add the error function after success like so `{ url.., success:.., error:function(){ console.log( arguments ) }}`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller and action are mixed up

```
var dummyURL = '@Url.Action("AddFoundPatient", "AddPatient", new { FirstName = "-1", LastName = "-2", DOB = "-3", MRN = "-4", EMPIID = "-5", popID = (int)TempData["POPULATIONID"] })';
```

Comment: I would try calling the service directly from your browser first, and try getting it to hit the breakpoint. Or you could use Fiddler.